# Auth0 Unknown URL Scheme

Tags: java, android, auth0

I implemented auth0 authentication webhook in my activity, that looks like this:

```
public void loginWithBrowser() {
        WebAuthProvider.login(account).withScheme("custom").withAudience("{redacted}")
                .withScope("openid profile email")
                .start(this, new Callback<Credentials, AuthenticationException>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Credentials credentials) {
                        //do stuff
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull com.auth0.android.authentication.AuthenticationException e) {
                        //do stuff
                    }

                });
    }
```

My manifest for this activity looks like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activities.LoginActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:resizeableActivity="false"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="custom" android:host="callback" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

What is interesting is that on my native phone, this flow works perfectly, but on another phone, this results on my web browser with the `net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL-SCHEME`. What I did notice was that for the phone that works, this webhook flow is run within the app with a web browser is apart of the app, whereas with the phone that does not work, this flow opens up my default web browser (another web browser that is not in the same app), so I suspect this may be the issue. Any ideas how to resolve this problem? Without changing the default web browser, how do I have the webhook not open another browser to resolve this url, or have 3rd party web browsers recognize this URL scheme?

Thanks